# why with .asBitmap() in Glide 4.9.0 it crashes

Tags: crash, android-glide

Just upgrade to Glide 4.9.0, 
In kotlin extension `ImageView.loadImg`, with .asBitmap() it crashes, but without .asBitmap()  it works fine for same imageUrl (which loads the image fine in browser)

```
fun ImageView.loadImg(imageUrl: String) {
    var requestOptions : RequestOptions  = RequestOptions()
    requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    requestOptions.error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
        GlideApp.with(this.context)
            .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
            .asBitmap()  //this one causes crash
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(this)
    }
}
```

which happened at the `setImageBitmap()` of a iamgeView derived from AppCompatImageView,  when call customImageView?.loadImg(imageUrl):

```
class CustomImageView : AppCompatImageView {

    ... ...

    override fun setImageBitmap(bm: Bitmap) {//<== crash at here
        super.setImageBitmap(bm)
        bitmap = bm
    }
}
```

Is there problem to not using the `.asBitmap()`?
any idea?